# REST API Best Practices for Hierarchical JSON Objects

Tags: java, json, rest

Imagine a simple example like 'Vehicle Make and Model' REST API with CRUD methods implemented.

The relation between Vehicle Make to Model is 1:N. One vehicle make can have N models in it, but, one model is assosiated with just one make.

Our CRUD methods:

- POST/PUT vehicles/makes: To create or update basic info about one vehicle make.
- GET vehicles/makes: To get a list of vehicle makes.
- GET vehicles/makes/{id}: To get a specific vehicle make with their info.
- POST/PUT vehicles/makes/{id}/models: To create or update basic info about one vehicle model.
- GET vehicles/makes/{id}/models: To get a list of vehicle models of a specific make.
- GET vehicles/makes/{id}/models/{id}: To get a specific vehicle model of a specific make.

**The question is:**

Should the `GET makes or makes/{id}` return in it a list of theirs models? Or maybe, should the models be returned only in a specific request?

What must I consider to return or not a nested info in my API?

---

The example is a quite simple, but the scenario can be expanded in a way with a lot of hierarchical dependencies, like:

```
vehicle
├── vehicle_make
│   ├── vehicle_model
│   └── ...
├── tires
│   └── tire_brand
│       ├── tire_model
│       └── ...
└── ...
└── ...
```

Comment: I work for a company where we actually have a vehicle lookup service and have a similar sort of rest API format. For us `vehicle/makes/{id}` returns nothing, it's not a valid endpoint for us because there is nothing specific for make. You would need to do a search for models to get a list of models back, so you would do `vehicles/makes/{id}/models`. 

What is interesting though is should it be `vehicle/make/{id}/models`. Remember is the resource you are requesting a Singleton or a Collection? `models` would return a collection, `model` would return a singleton.

Comment: Maybe you want to check out `graphql` since graphs are more suitable for your use-case, I guess.

Comment: @Popeye I'm trying to keep the Rest concepts. A good practice is to use plural on resource path: [good-restful-url-examples](https://apiguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_and_publish/use_RESTful_urls.html#good-restful-url-examples).

Comment: @Shahriar Unfortunately, `graphql` is not an option for the project ;(

Comment: I think this is a great question, however it solicits answers that are probably opinion-based (off-topic for SO) and I wonder if another StackExchange site would be more appropriate (?) ... this is something I commonly struggle with when considering REST APIs.

Comment: @diogenes_vz there are actually 4 resource archetypes that you would only use plurals on 2 of them for. The 4 archetypes are `document`, `collection`,  `store` and `controller`. You would only use plurals on `collection` and `store`. You would use verbs on `controller` and you would use  nouns on `document`. So you might use `http://api.example.com/song-management/users/{id}/playlists` for storing but you would use `http://api.example.com/song-management/users/{id}/playlist/play` as the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends.

Who is the consumer of those APIs ? If its your own UI, another service or direct customers ?

Aim is to reduce the number of server calls.
If consumer of the service is making multiple calls every time to get the required data, then it should be nested into single response.
If your UI is using lazy loading, or other consumers need those data conditionally, then segregate into multiple APIs.